# Getting values from file if match found for lines with same id in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, file-io, readlines

I have a file with lines of data. Each line starts with an id, followed by fixed set of attributes separated by comma.

```
123,2,kent,...,
123,2,bob,...,
123,2,sarah,...,
123,8,may,...,

154,4,sheila,...,
154,4,jeff,...,

175,3,bob,...,

249,2,jack,...,
249,5,bob,...,
249,3,rose,...,
```

I would like to get an attribute if the conditions are met. The conditions are if 'bob' appears within the same id, get the value of the second attribute that follows.

```
For example:

id: 123
values returned: 2, 8

id: 249
values returned: 3
```

Java has a double loop I can use, but I would like to try this in Python. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Why the `values returned` of the id 249 is `3` instead of `2, 5, 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a (perhaps) more pythonic solution which uses [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`dropwhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile). This method yields the same result as the below method, but I think it's prettier.. :) Flags, "curr_id" and stuff like that is not very pythonic, and should be avoided if possible!

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby, dropwhile

goal = 'bob'
ids = {}

with open('my_data.csv') as ifile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    for key, rows in groupby(reader, key=lambda r: r[0]):
        matched_rows = list(dropwhile(lambda r: r[2] != goal, rows))
        if len(matched_rows) > 1:
            ids[key] = [row[1] for row in matched_rows[1:]]

print ids
```

---

*(first solution below)*

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

curr_id = None
found = False
goal = 'bob'
ids = defaultdict(list)

with open('my_data.csv') as ifile:
    for row in csv.reader(ifile):
        if row[0] != curr_id:
            found = False
            curr_id = row[0]
        if found:
            ids[curr_id].append(row[1])
        elif row[2] == goal:
            found = True

print dict(ids)
```

**Output:**

```
{'123': ['2', '8'], '249': ['3']}
```

Comment: +1 Ah that's better than my answer which is similar however it has an empty list for 175

Comment: @bernie Thanks man, but I'm not satisfied with this solution - I don't like using flags, curr_id and stuff... :)

Comment: @bernie I found another solution if it interests you :)

Comment: Very clean. Takes advantage of the data already being sorted by ID.

Comment: Thanks Steinar Lima for the answer! It worked exactly as I want and you were able to figure out the file I was trying to read is actually a csv.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a flag or something as you loop through:

```
name = 'bob'
id = '123'
found = False

for line in file:
    l = line.split(',')
    if l[0] == id:
        if l[2] == name:
            found = True
        if found:
            print l[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv, collections as co, cStringIO as StringIO

s = '''123,2,kent,...,
123,2,bob,...,
123,2,sarah,...,
123,8,may,...,
154,4,sheila,...,
154,4,jeff,...,
175,3,bob,...,
249,2,jack,...,
249,5,bob,...,
249,3,rose,...,'''

filelikeobject = StringIO.StringIO(s)
dd = co.defaultdict(list)
cr = csv.reader(filelikeobject)
for line in cr:
  if line[2] == 'bob':
    dd[line[0]]; continue
  if line[0] in dd:
    dd[line[0]].append(line[1])
```

Result:

```
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'175': [], '123': ['2', '8'], '249': ['3']})
```